# When logged in Start Quiz

Tags: python

I would like a little bit of help because Im confused and also really stuck on this. I would like to point out that I am a bigger on python so please take it easy.

I am trying to create a simple quiz with a login/register dictionary system. I am also trying to keep all my "Registered Users" in a .txt file but i can't do that unfortunately so if anyone can help I would be delighted!

The problem is, when a users logs in or -registers i would like the quiz bit to run, but instead the login/register runs in a loop unless i take away the while statement, but if I do take it away the login/register script does not run at all. So what i need is.....

> When my program runs, I want it to run the login/register script but
>   then when the user has registered or logged on I want it to start the
>   quiz.

Here is my code,

```
 #Login & Register
users = {}
status = ""


def displayMenu():
    status = input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Say quit to exit: ")  
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()

def newUser():
    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in users: # check if login name exists
        print ("\nLogin name already exist!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw # add login and password
        print("\nUser created!\n")     

def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    # check if user exists and login matches password
    if login in users and users[login] == passw: 
        print ("\nLogin successful!\n")
    else:
        print ("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")

while status != "q":            
    displayMenu()

# Defining Score variables 
x = 0
score = x

# Question One 
print("When did WW2 finish?")
answer1 = input("a)2001\nb)1945\nc)1877\nd)1940\n:")
if answer1.lower() == "b" or answer1.lower() == "2":
    print("Correct")
    x = x + 1   
else:
    print("Incorrect, the second Worl War ended in 1945")

# Question Two
print("Who was responsilbe of most deaths in World War 1 & 2 ")
answer2 = input("a)Donald Trump\nb)Adolf Hitler\nc)Tom Cruisend\nd)There were no WAR\n:")
if answer2.lower() == "b" or answer1.lower() == "Adolf Hitler":
    print("Correct")
    x = x + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect, It was Adolf Hitler who took around 12 to 14 million lives")

# Question Three
print("True or False... Hitler was a painter")
answer3 = input(":")
if answer3.lower() == "true" or answer3.lower() == "t":
    print("Correct")
    x = x + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect")  

# Question Four
print("What happened in Chernobyl")
answer4 = input("a)Nuclear Plant exploaded\nb)Water Flood\nc)Alien Envasion\nd)War\n:")
if answer4.lower() == "a" or answer4 == "1967":
    print("Correct")
    x = x + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect, the nuclear plant exploaded")

# Question Five 
print("True or False... Everybody knew the reactor will explode")
answer5 = input(":")
if answer5.lower() == "false" or answer5.lower() == "f":
    print("Correct")
    x = x + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect, no one knew it will explode")


#Total Score
score = float(x / 5) * 100
print(x,"out of 5, that is",score, "%")
```

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the while loop add a `break` statement:

```
while status != "q":            
    displayMenu()
    break
```

Comment: Thats not going to work because if the user does have an account and says "y" it will take them straight to the quiz not asking for the credentials

Answer (score 1):

your status does not exist beyond the scope of the function DisplayMenu()

What you can do is use status as a return value for this function, adding

```
return status
```

in the end, and then using a condition on this :

```
dm=""
while dm != "q":            
    dm=displayMenu()
```

Comment: Could you edit the whole code for me, I don't understand where to put these commands.